# Creating a pointer to an object in the heap of a different type

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory

Say we have a class `Mammal` and a class `Dog`. `Dog` inherits some of its members from `Mammal` through the code `class Dog : public Mammal {};`.

Now, in the book I'm reading, it initializes a pointer in main using the code `Mammal *pDog = new Dog`. The question I'm asking is, why is the `Mammal` pointer being used to point to a `Dog` in the heap?

Wouldn't the code `Dog *pDog = new Dog` make more sense and be more readable? Or are there advantages to using the former code?

Comment: Google for polymorphism please!

Comment: I've replaced "space" by "object" in the title. What you're doing here is called Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: I find it hard to believe this book provided examples like this without explaining the fundamental pattern they are implementing, but if it did, you need to get a different book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or are there advantages to using the former code?

Sure, client code doesn't need to know if `Mammal` is a `Dog` or a `Giraffe` actually. It's called **polymorphism**.

Both might provide functions like `pee();` and `poop();` using completely different implementations:

```
class Mammal {
public:
    virtual void pee() = 0;
    virtual void poop() = 0;
    virtual ~Mammal() {}
};

class Dog : public Mammal {
public:
    virtual void pee() {
        // Doggy style
    }
    virtual void poop() {
        // Doggy style
    }  
};

class Giraffe : public Mammal {
public:
    virtual void pee() {
        // Giraffe style
    }
    virtual void poop() {
        // Giraffe style
    }  
};
```

A client function may just want a `Mammal` pointer or reference, without knowing what kind of `Mammal` was actually passed:

```
void doTheInevitable(Mammal* m) {
    m->pee();
    m->poop();
}
```

---

```
Dog dog;
Giraffe giraffe;

doTheInevitable(&dog);
doTheInevitable(&giraffe);
```

but the specific implementations still apply.

Comment: I understand that they can both use different implementations of `pee();` and `poop();`, but if I want `Dog` to use a different implementation, I can just do `Dog *pDog = new Dog`. My question is, in what situation would I ever want to use `Mammal *pDog = new Dog`?

Comment: You can have vector<Mammal*> and work with them w/o knowing which one exactly **Dog** or **Giraffe**. This is **polymorphism** purpose.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense looking at the example. Thank you!

Comment: @PaulT. Sorry using that kinda disgusting example, but that was one I found inevitable with mammals (or other kind of fauna) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing code that's only intended to work with dogs, then you would use `Dog *pDog = new Dog;`. But if you have a more general application that works with any type of mammal, you write `Mammap *pDog = new Dog;`, and then pass that pointer to the generic function. It can then call the member functions declared in the `Mammal` base class, and but if `Dog` overrides them it will get the Dog-specific behavior.

This is the essence of polymorphism. It allows you to write general-purpose functions, and then use them with instances of more specific types.